# Highest known block in the peer network - permissioned ethereum network

Tags: synchronization, blocks, besu

We are starting to define the best metrics to monitor a permissioned Besu network.

One important point to monitor is the block height of a node and from other nodes in order to discover if the node is not in the last block.

I saw in Hyperledger Besu doc [1] that it is possible to query not only the own block height but also the best well-known block height (from other nodes in the network).

It was a good surprise to discover that the own nodes try to check if it is updated or not. Of course, if the node is not syncing this info will not be useful anyway.

Anyone using this can confirm that I am thinking correctly? Since the name of this metric starts with ethereum (ethereum_best_known_block_number) it is common to other ethereum clients...

[1] https://besu.hyperledger.org/en/stable/Reference/API-Methods/#eth_syncing